# HttpContext not in System.Web visual studio community 2015

Tags: c#, url, screen-scraping, httpcontext, system.web

After looking up how to retrieve a URL in c#, I kept seeing people talking about HttpContext, I'm already using system.Web and was trying to access HttpContext, but I can not. Please help me. What I am really wanting to do is to preform a Google search using advanced google search keywords like "site:" or "filetype:", and then retrieve the URL of the search result similar to this:

https://www.google.com/search?num=100&espv=2&q=how+to+get+a+sites+URL+in+c%23&oq=how+to+get+a+sites+URL+in+c%23&gs_l=serp.3..0i22i30l5.26966.34827.0.35214.30.27.1.0.0.0.172.2717.5j18.23.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..6.24.2714.WDtiO7ruPvo

Comment: HttpContext allow you to retrieve the url of the client when you're on the server side. Maybe you sshould take a look at HttpClient?

Comment: ok, thank you, i'll look more into httpclient

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
public static async Task Test()
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(@"https://google.ca");
    string responseUrl = response.RequestMessage.RequestUri.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I just looked at how google formats its URLs for searches and added that as apart of the string like: string html = web.DownloadString("http://google.com/search?q=site:" + input + webExtCombo.Text + "+inurl:/");